# Gradle Error:Could not create an instance of type com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool

Tags: java, gradle

I created a new root folder & it contains build.gradle with `apply plugin ="java"`
A folder src -> main -> java  (contains code)
When I run `gradle assemble` I'm getting this error

> Could not create an instance of type com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.
>
> :compileJava failed
>
> :processResources UP-TO-DATE

Why is my build process not successful?(i'm on ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: below answer solved my problem check it [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39269429/5208491)

Answer (score 5):

Switch your build to use [Gradle 3.3](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/release-notes.html) quickly by updating your wrapper properties:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=3.3
```

Answer (score 5):

For me it was caused because I had multiples Java environments (**openjdk-8** & **openjdk-9**)  on my laptop.

So I began to remove one environment:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove openjdk-9-*
```

And then I set `JAVA_HOME` to **openjdk-8**. Just had

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
```

To your *.bashrc* file *(you may need to correct the link according to your system)*

And that's it.