# android studio cannot compile when using realm database

Tags: android, realm

I want to use realm database in my app for that i add this lines to my build.gradle file in app

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
    }
}
```

and this is my table code:

```
public class Country extends RealmObject {
@Ignore
public static String NAME="name";
@Ignore
public static String POPULATION="population";
@PrimaryKey
private String name;
private int population;

public Country() { }

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPopulation() {
    return population;
}

public void setPopulation(int population) {
    this.population = population;
}

}
```

but when I use this code and nothing else "I mean never use country table" I getting this error when run my app:

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_05). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
 com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for rx.Observable not found
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

my app.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sss.ddd"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

}
```

and this is my project.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

can anyone help me abou this?
thanks.

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Try to do `./gradlew assemble --refresh-dependencies`

Answer (score 5):

Thanks all For your attentions but I found my solution.
I add this lines to my project Gradle file:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
    }

}
}
```

and this to my app gradle file

```
compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:0.9.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
```

I don't know why I should add this lines and realm documentation never refer to this but know my project works fine.
I know this is wired behavior but its work.
please share me if you know a better answer.

Comment: this is the solution. Thanks.

Comment: i also cannot understand the reason. but this worked for me too

Comment: What if you use RxJava 2 and just cannot add first rxjava to `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1):

Updating JDK to version 1.8.3 solved the issue.
JDK can be downloaded from

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Setting up JDK on android can be done using
[How to set Java SDK path in AndroidStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608742/how-to-set-java-sdk-path-in-androidstudio)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current one seems to be a hard workaround and it does not work for me.

Comment: This did not resolve my issue. where as Max's solution worked for me. with Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:

1.) Create a new package and name it rx
2.) Inside this package add a class named Observable, empty class.

It compiles fine now.