# You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle?

Tags: java, android, flutter, sdk, build.gradle

Was building app using flutter and vs code ,I had **not installed android studio** can i know how to upgrade Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment.

My java version

```
C:\Android\cmdline-tools\tools>java -version
java version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Version displaying in `flutter doctor -v`

```
• Android SDK at C:\Android\
• Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android
• Java binary at: C:\Android\openjdk\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_202-b08)
• All Android licenses accepted.
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur) is of the same kind.

Comment: did your find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here was I had not linked my java path to flutter SDK. You can know more about it at  [How to change java version for flutter package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853635/how-to-change-java-version-for-flutter-package#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20File%20%3E%20Project%20Structure,JDK%20in%20the%20text%20box.)