# Flutter"Unable to determine bundled Java version" for Android Studio version3.6

Tags: android, flutter, dart

First I get error is android license status unknown .So I reinstall again. they thrown two error like the picture below. So how i go to fix it.

````
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.867], locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (1 year, 2 months ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup      for detailed instructions.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] VS Code (version 1.55.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • INE LX2 • JUC4C18801000395 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

    ```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to find bundled Java version on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter)

Comment: not ,i see this post yesterday and try .Still cannot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter?rq=1

This is a perfect answer... and has helped alot of people.. check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should specify the path to your Java SDK in  Android Studio, you can set it by doing the following:

> Generally speaking, it is set in the "Project Structure" dialog.
>
> Go to File > Project Structure > SDK Location. The third field is "JDK
> Location" where you can set it. This will set it for the current
> project.

[How to set Java SDK path in AndroidStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608742/how-to-set-java-sdk-path-in-androidstudio)

Comment: It means i want to set jdk location(path) is same with my java home?

Comment: I try set it with same with javahome ,but cannot the flutter still same

Comment: I think it would be good if you upgrade your flutter version, it looks like your on version  v1.12.13+hotfix.8 but v2 is already out  so please upgrade and check if the problem remains

Answer (score 3):

try setting a symbol to jdk, like this

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
ln -s ../jre jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps to resolve in M1 chip version

```sh
 ~ % cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
jre % ln -s ../jre jdk
jre % ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
jre % flutter doctor -v
```

Terminal output screenshot

[image]

Comment: solving my problem, thanks.
but now i get Android Licenses error.
running flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema

Comment: solved, android-licenses error Exception by installing Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) 