# Android Studio JDK location missing

Tags: android-studio

I'm using *Android Studio 2020.3.1 canary 14.* I open the *Project Structure pane* to set the JDK location but there is no *JDK location* listed.
[image: project structure pane]

EDIT: After hours searching, it's look like Android Studio canary 14 do not have JDK location. I have found a solution using stable or beta version to set JDK location and then open it in canary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you [Run a Java project](https://rvganesh.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/run-java-project-in-android-studio/)
2. And follow the answers of the same question: [android studio - How to set Java SDK path in AndroidStudio? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608742/how-to-set-java-sdk-path-in-androidstudio)

Answer (score -1):

If you navigate to the folder you're pointing there, can you see these?

[image]

If you can't, I would suggest you reinstall the SDK, something is wrong.