# Force Android Studio to always use its own JRE for Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two JDKs installed on my Windows 10 computer:

- OpenJDK version 8
- JDK 11 which comes built-in with Android Studio (under `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`). (Minor unrelated question: Why is the JDK under a folder named `jre`? Doesn't make any sense...)

Every time I create a new empty project from scratch and try to run it, Android Studio complains:

```
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

I think this happens because my `PATH` environment variable points to OpenJDK 8. Ideally I shouldn't touch this (because I use it for other projects).

I normally solve this problem by going to `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle` and set the JDK to Android's Built-in JDK.

But this is too tiresome: I need to do this for EVERY project I create. I haven't found a way to tell Android Studio: "Hey, use your own JDK by default for every new project, and stop complaining."

I want to know if such way exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Java SDK path in AndroidStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608742/how-to-set-java-sdk-path-in-androidstudio)

Comment: Not really. It just sets the JDK for the current project, but not for the new ones.